# 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable in Azure databricks

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am getting below error while importing camelot package

TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable

```
!pip install PyPDF2
!pip install bs4
!pip install camelot-py[cv]
!pip install tabula-py

from urllib import request
import requests
import traceback
import re
import os
import urllib
import tabula
from tabula.io import read_pdf
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import camelot
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution.

The current version 4.8.0.76 of opencv-python does not work, use 4.8.0.74.
Install both packages seperately.

In your workbook include the following statements:

```
%pip install opencv-python==4.8.0.74
%pip install camelot-py
dbutils.library.restartPython()
```

Comment: The best solution.  other stackOverflow answers did'nt solve this issue.